# ESTEASY003650: No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to get a Token from the Intranet Server and in the process getting error 
    RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header

Using `Java 11 API`. I have already tried using postman and the client works like a charm but trying to do as a stand alone java application. This is the code in main application

```
try {

    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
          .uri(URI.create("http://myurl:8480/rest/v1/auth/token"))     
           .setHeader("client_id", "rest-client")
           .setHeader("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
           .setHeader("username", "user")
           .setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
           .setHeader("password", "password")
           .build();

       client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
          .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
          .thenAccept(System.out::println)
          .join();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("MalformedURLException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I should get a token in response. I am getting this error

> {   "error" : {
>       "code" : "500",
>       "target" : "context",
>       "details" : [ {
>         "message" : "javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header",
>         "code" : "NotAllowedException"
>       } ]   }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [405 Method Not Allowed is coming as Http Status 500 in RestEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374177/405-method-not-allowed-is-coming-as-http-status-500-in-resteasy)

Comment: Can you post more of this server side code and Postman working?

Comment: This is not duplicate issue Cgrim, Kosonome, I have pasted the whole code and this is embedded in a stand alone Java class with the main function. I use the same parameter in postman what you see here. The server side i will post issue. client application like Postman and Swagger are working fine